# Access Form won't accept input in text boxes

Tags: forms, ms-access, input, ms-access-2010

So I have a form in Access.![acessform1][1]

Here are form properties[image]

I got this database and have been making adjustments to the other forms. I gave the database back to the user and they reported an issue that this form is not acting properly, and the add order record function is not working anymore.

There's an Add Order Record button on the right side of the form that would usually add the record if the user manually entered input into some of the boxes. The old form you would have control of the values 1/0 for yes/no. You can enter text into the notes boxes.

This functionality doesn't work anymore, and I can't seem to figure out why. The form is identical to the original and no adjustments have been made except to the table that it pulls data from.

So the symptoms are:

User input is not accepted in text boxes.

The find CP functionality works with the drop down and reflects the records accurately but I cannot update the fields.

Also, the fields CP_Ref and Invoice date don't let me enter data anymore.

Also the Add Order Record was giving me an error that The it could not find the record specified, but I since copied the original form back into place and that error went away.

I think functionality wise this button should save the record after a field is updated and should add a new record.

Seems like all the controls are locked on the page.

Here is the query that pulls the data when I click the button that takes me to the Order form.

```
    SELECT DISTINCTROW CPOrders.Cust, Customer.NAME, CPOrders.CP_Ref, CPOrders.Slsman, 
CPOrders.Date_opn, CPOrders.CPSmall, CPOrders.InvIssu, CPOrders.InvNo, 
CPOrders.InvDate, CPOrders.DueDate, CPOrders.ETADate, CPOrders.Closed, 
CPOrders.Cust, CPOrders.Name, CPOrders.BuyerRef, CPOrders.ToCity, 
CPOrders.ToState, CPOrders.ToCtry, CPOrders.ToPort, CPOrders.Supplier, 
CPOrders.Origin, CPOrders.Product, CPOrders.GradeType, CPOrders.NoUnits, 
CPOrders.Pkg, CPOrders.Qty, CPOrders.TotSale, CPOrders.TotCost, 
CPOrders.GrMargin, CPOrders.[Sale$/Unit], CPOrders.[Cost$/Unit], 
CPOrders.OceanCost, CPOrders.OceanNotes, CPOrders.BLadingDate, 
CPOrders.USAPort, CPOrders.FOBCost, CPOrders.FASExportVal, 
CPOrders.InlandFrt, CPOrders.CommodCode, CPOrders.Notes, 
CPOrders.ProjCust, CPOrders.ProjValue, CPOrders.ContainerNumber, 
CPOrders.Vessel, Customer.TERMS
    FROM Customer INNER JOIN CPOrders ON Customer.[CUST_#] = CPOrders.Cust
    ORDER BY CPOrders.CP_Ref;
```

Comment: What changes were made to the table?

Comment: I added a field called vessel which i was trying to add a field for them to enter in the form. But I created it, set the control source, and i thought everything was working fine. then i updated the table with the production data and sent it back.

Comment: What data type is the field?

Comment: Field name is Vessel - Text (55)

Comment: it's text but they are all null values because it's an addition to the table and there's existing records. Does the same principal apply?

Comment: Does the database field allow nulls?

Comment: it is not a required field.

Comment: When you say 'User input is not accepted in text boxes', what _exactly_ is happening? I.e., is there an error message? Or some other behaviour?

Comment: @Yawar no it's no error other then when I click the Accept order Record button. The text fields just don't register my input. So I'll go into CP_Ref column and enter a new number, and the input doesn't register. so it stays blank. Same with Invoice Date. It pops up a calendar, when I select a date, nothing is input into the box...

Comment: if that query is the record source for the form, then you can't use an aggregate (DISTINCT) query.

Comment: why it's always been like this? I'll try it.

Comment: That was not the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up checking several locations for the answer to this.

What it ended up being was a primary key issue.

Essentially when I got the updated database I put them into new tables, effectively destroying the dependencies, relationships, and established keys.

I reverted back to the old tables and found out the form worked properly.

The issue ultimately was that the primary keys were not defined as needed for the table to be updated.